# multiple domains on one sever using nginx

Tags: server, nginx

I want to run multi websites on one servis, the problem is both domains redirect to domain1

domain1.com.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/domain1;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;



        location / {
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                     
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
```

domain2.com.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/domain2;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;



        location / {
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                     
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
```

Comment: Are these in separate configuration files?  Are they both present in /etc/nginx/sites-available AND /etc/nginx/sites-enabled?  Have you erased your web browser cache?

Comment: Sorry but did you literally copied these from a tutorial?  You do realize you need to alter them to domains you own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of my nginx virtual host configs..  This one works so really I think its down to those arcane fastcgi params.`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name collect.local;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/html/collectd-html;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I would suspect these..

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
```